# Can't see the block body

Tags: blocks

I'm working on a drupal site. Its already done by someone else but I have to change some things. I want to edit a block but when I want to edit, it doesn't show the block body. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Oun.png

Comment: Where does block body come from?

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is a block provided by a view.
Look at the block edit page url, it usually gives you a hint wich module provides the block: "admin/structure/block/manage/**views**/what_we_offer-block"...

Comment: What to do next?

Comment: got to admin/structure/views, there you will find a list with all your views. One of them provides the "What we offer" block.

Comment: this is the page: http://imgur.com/G9rHLKt

Comment: Don't know dutch, but if you look at the views filter criteria you will realize it shows the newest 3 published nodes of type "article" and the taxonomy term "offer". If you want to change one of these articles, go to admin/content, filter for content type "article" end edit the articles, or  add a new one with taxonomy term "offer" set and it should show up.

Comment: So which settings do I change so that I can edit a block properly?

Comment: What do you want to edit in specific?

Comment: The content of the block, so basically the body. In the future I'm probably going to edit some HTML aswell.

Comment: very simplified, the content of the block will change when you edit the articles that this view returns. See admin/content... 
The html structure you could change by editing the view
But without more details it is hard to help

Comment: Okay thanks! Now i've got some subdomains which almost have the same content, but some different numbers etc..  to change the content/links in the block I need to change filter criteria to match a newly created article page?

Comment: followup: i can't seem to change an individual subdomain's settings as it seems to inherit the main site's settings and links me directly to the main settings instead of the subdomain's. How can I change them individually?

Comment: I would rather add the "offer" tag to the newly created article page - it should then automatically show up in your block/view. Of course the oldest of the three articles shown will disappear - see views "Paginaring" settings.

Comment: Yeah I made a new offer tag specifically for my subdomain, however when I changed it in what seemed my subdomain's settings it actually changed every version of the site, including the main site and the other subdomains? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

The block is most like being generated by a module. It could be a view block if it's a list of content, or it could be a module that's causing it.

First I would check views, at /admin/structure/views. The url of your block contains "views," which makes me think that's whats generating the view (I'm not 100% sure about this, but I believe that the structure for block edit links is: admin/structure/block/manage/(Module making the block)/(block machine name)/configure ).

Look for the view that's generating the block, and edit it from there. Keep in mind that views are theme-able, and there may be a views template that is overriding the output as well. So if you have content that is appearing in your block that dosn't seem to be generated by the view, check to see if there is a view template being applied. To do this, click on "Advanced" in the view menu, then "Theming Information". The templates that are being used are bolded. Anything that is bolded beyond the first in the list will be a custom template and would be editable in your theme folder.

Again, I'm fairly sure this is coming from views, but for anyone else out there who stumbles upon this trying to find where a block is coming from, it could also be a custom template block. If you have any custom modules running on the site, that would be a good place to look. If you do have custom modules, look for [hook_block_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7), if that is in there and contains something like this:

```
$blocks['what_we_offer'] = array(
    'info' => t('YOUR BLOCK'),
  );
```

then your looking in the right place.